# Is there any front-end framework for data-driven websites?

Tags: ajax, jsp, frontend

I'am responsible for data-driven websites in my company. The websites are dynamic and fetch all data and info from database, almost all the contents display in pages are fetching through Javascript ajax and API interface. 
Basically I use ajax to send request and get data back, after the server response with data, I will use Jquery to append all the data into the pages. But this is quiet inefficient and difficult to construct into modules.
Any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: The **only** way to retrieve back-end data from the front-end is to make a `GET` / `POST` request. You're basically restricted to only jQuery or AJAX if you don't want to use a back-end language.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Well, it is **not** the **only** way (see e.g. [WebSockets](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html)), but it is the most common and well supported in most (if not all) JS frameworks.